# Google charts don't work when uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to use Google Charts with Firefox. When I copy an example code from Google and save it to an html file on the desktop, the chart works correctly. If I upload the same html file, the chart does not work and I receive the error: ReferenceError: google is not defined. I have created an [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/84kemxwb/) of the code I am using.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I can correct the issue?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1);

      function drawChart1() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      9]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities',
          is3D: true,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your JSFiddle demo is working fine for me.

Comment: are there any errors in your browsers **developer** tools console - works in all browsers I tried, which browser are you using?

Comment: `ReferenceError: google is not defined` - implies the external script is failing to load - the console will show you that

Comment: I am using Firefox 53.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered an add-on was installed in Firefox called Google Disconnect. As soon as the add-on was disabled, the graphs started working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      9]
        ]);
```

You should make your code more clearer:

```
function drawChart() {


 // Define the chart to be drawn.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Element');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Percentage');
  data.addRows([
    [' string ', ' Element']

  ]);

  // Instantiate and draw the chart.
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('myPieChart'));
  chart.draw(data, null);
```

Google Charts libraries can show you why its more effective this way.
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs